# Why phpPgAdmin on ubuntu server shows message No objects found?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, phppgadmin

I try to run phpPgAdmin 5.1 under my remove ubuntu 18, but I see message

```
   No objects found.
```

I uploaded phppgadmin from github and downloaded it under /var/www/html
File   /var/www/html/phppgadmin/conf/config.inc.php have :

```
root@hoster-server:~# cat   /var/www/html/phppgadmin/conf/config.inc.php
<?php

        /**
         * Central phpPgAdmin configuration.  As a user you may modify the
         * settings here for your particular configuration.
         *
         * $Id: config.inc.php-dist,v 1.55 2008/02/18 21:10:31 xzilla Exp $
         */

        // An example server.  Create as many of these as you wish,
        // indexed from zero upwards.

        // Display name for the server on the login screen
        $conf['servers'][0]['desc'] = 'PostgreSQL';

        // Hostname or IP address for server.  Use '' for UNIX domain socket.
        // use 'localhost' for TCP/IP connection on this computer
        $conf['servers'][0]['host'] = 'localhost';

        // Database port on server (5432 is the PostgreSQL default)
        $conf['servers'][0]['port'] = 5432;

        // Database SSL mode
        // Possible options: disable, allow, prefer, require
        // To require SSL on older servers use option: legacy
        // To ignore the SSL mode, use option: unspecified
        $conf['servers'][0]['sslmode'] = 'allow';

        // Change the default database only if you cannot connect to template1.
        // For a PostgreSQL 8.1+ server, you can set this to 'postgres'.
        $conf['servers'][0]['defaultdb'] = 'template1';

        // Specify the path to the database dump utilities for this server.
        // You can set these to '' if no dumper is available.
        $conf['servers'][0]['pg_dump_path'] = '/usr/bin/pg_dump';
        $conf['servers'][0]['pg_dumpall_path'] = '/usr/bin/pg_dumpall';

        // Example for a second server (PostgreSQL for Windows)
        //$conf['servers'][1]['desc'] = 'Test Server';
        //$conf['servers'][1]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
        //$conf['servers'][1]['port'] = 5432;
        //$conf['servers'][1]['sslmode'] = 'allow';
        //$conf['servers'][1]['defaultdb'] = 'template1';
        //$conf['servers'][1]['pg_dump_path'] = 'C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\8.0\\bin\\pg_dump.exe';
        //$conf['servers'][1]['pg_dumpall_path'] = 'C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\8.0\\bin\\pg_dumpall.exe';


        /* Groups definition */
        /* Groups allow administrators to logicaly group servers together under
         * group nodes in the left browser tree
         *
         * The group '0' description
         */
        //$conf['srv_groups'][0]['desc'] = 'group one';

        /* Add here servers indexes belonging to the group '0' separated by comma */
        //$conf['srv_groups'][0]['servers'] = '0,1,2';

        /* A server can belong to multi groups. Here server 1 is referenced in both
         * 'group one' and 'group two'*/
        //$conf['srv_groups'][1]['desc'] = 'group two';
        //$conf['srv_groups'][1]['servers'] = '3,1';

        /* A group can be nested in one or more existing groups using the 'parents'
         * parameter. Here the group 'group three' contains only one server and will
         * appear as a subgroup in both 'group one' and 'group two':
         */
        //$conf['srv_groups'][2]['desc'] = 'group three';
        //$conf['srv_groups'][2]['servers'] = '4';
        //$conf['srv_groups'][2]['parents'] = '0,1';

        /* Warning: Only groups with no parents appears at the root of the tree. */

        /* You can apply specific theme depending on servers, users and databases
         * The priority order is :
         *   * the theme defined for a server
         *   * the theme defined for a database apply over the server one
         *   * the theme defined for a user apply over the database one
         */
        /* Example for servers */
        //$conf['servers'][0]['theme']['default'] = 'default';
        /* Example for users */
        //$conf['servers'][0]['theme']['user']['specific_user'] = 'default';
        /* Example for databases */
        //$conf['servers'][0]['theme']['db']['specific_db'] = 'default';

        // Default language. E.g.: 'english', 'polish', etc.  See lang/ directory
        // for all possibilities. If you specify 'auto' (the default) it will use
        // your browser preference.
        $conf['default_lang'] = 'auto';

        // AutoComplete uses AJAX interaction to list foreign key values
        // on insert fields. It currently only works on single column
        // foreign keys. You can choose one of the following values:
        // 'default on' enables AutoComplete and turns it on by default.
        // 'default off' enables AutoComplete but turns it off by default.
        // 'disable' disables AutoComplete.
        $conf['autocomplete'] = 'default on';

        // If extra login security is true, then logins via phpPgAdmin with no
        // password or certain usernames (pgsql, postgres, root, administrator)
        // will be denied. Only set this false once you have read the FAQ and
        // understand how to change PostgreSQL's pg_hba.conf to enable
        // passworded local connections.
        $conf['extra_login_security'] = false;

        // Only show owned databases?
        // Note: This will simply hide other databases in the list - this does
        // not in any way prevent your users from seeing other database by
        // other means. (e.g. Run 'SELECT * FROM pg_database' in the SQL area.)
        $conf['owned_only'] = false;

        // Display comments on objects?  Comments are a good way of documenting
        // a database, but they do take up space in the interface.
        $conf['show_comments'] = true;

        // Display "advanced" objects? Setting this to true will show
        // aggregates, types, operators, operator classes, conversions,
        // languages and casts in phpPgAdmin. These objects are rarely
        // administered and can clutter the interface.
        $conf['show_advanced'] = false;

        // Display "system" objects?
        $conf['show_system'] = false;

        // Minimum length users can set their password to.
        $conf['min_password_length'] = 1;

        // Width of the left frame in pixels (object browser)
        $conf['left_width'] = 200;

        // Which look & feel theme to use
        $conf['theme'] = 'default';

        // Show OIDs when browsing tables?
        // Only supported in versions <=11
        $conf['show_oids'] = false;

        // Max rows to show on a page when browsing record sets
        $conf['max_rows'] = 30;

        // Max chars of each field to display by default in browse mode
        $conf['max_chars'] = 50;

        // Send XHTML strict headers?
        $conf['use_xhtml_strict'] = false;

        // Base URL for PostgreSQL documentation.
        // '%s', if present, will be replaced with the PostgreSQL version
        // (e.g. 8.4 )
        $conf['help_base'] = 'http://www.postgresql.org/docs/%s/interactive/';

        // Configuration for ajax scripts
        // Time in seconds. If set to 0, refreshing data using ajax will be disabled (locks and activity pages)
        $conf['ajax_refresh'] = 3;

        /** Plugins management
         * Add plugin names to the following array to activate them
         * Example:
         *   $conf['plugins'] = array(
         *     'Example',
         *     'Slony'
         *   );
         */
        $conf['plugins'] = array();

        /*****************************************
         * Don't modify anything below this line *
         *****************************************/

        $conf['version'] = 19;

?>
```

I set

```
$conf['extra_login_security'] = false;
```

As that is dev server I do not need to stuff security rules.
I am not sure where have I to set password to postgres? Could it be reason of the error ?

In my OS I have :

```
root@hoster-server:~# uname -a
Linux hoster-server 4.15.0-197-generic #208-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 1 17:23:37 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@hoster-server:~# sudo service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2023-07-21 06:05:49 UTC; 1min 52s ago
  Process: 1288 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1288 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 21 06:05:49 hoster-server systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...


root@hoster-server:~# php -v
PHP 8.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2022 09:39:35) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.1.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
root@hoster-server:~# sudo -u postgres psql
could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied
psql (10.23 (Ubuntu 10.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.2))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SELECT * from version();
version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PostgreSQL 10.23 (Ubuntu 10.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

I manually created a new db under console...

phpinfo shows :

```
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL   enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   10.23
...
PostgreSQL (libpq) Version  10.23
Multibyte character support enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
```

How to run it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a problem? Sounds like it is running fine and just letting you know your database is empty.

Comment: But I have added a new database with command : CREATE database DBNAME OWNER postgres ; - I expected to see it

Comment: @PetroGromovo 
SELECT datname, datdba FROM pg_database; to re assure for permission  or try with su to set password